# Pagination failed in LinkedIn API Marketing Developer Platform AdAnalyticsV2

Tags: linkedin-api

I've been trying to retrieve Ad Analytics data referring [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/ads-reporting/ads-reporting)

It seems the output from the API is separated into pieces using pagination.
So I followed [the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/api-guide/concepts/pagination?context=linkedin/marketing/context) explaining how to perform pagination in LinkedIn API. However, I keep experiencing ***'Setting a paging start value is not permitted'*** error. This does not happen when I request the first page but every time I request 'next page', the error encounters.

Here is what I did in Python:

```
import requests
# Define token, base_url, and parameters
headers = {'Authorization':'Bearer ' + 'MY_TOKEN'}
base_url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2/'
params = {
    'q': 'analytics',
    'dateRange.start.month': '4',
    'dateRange.start.day': '1',
    'dateRange.start.year': '2019',
    'timeGranularity': 'DAILY',
    'pivot': 'CREATIVE',
    'accounts':'MY_ACCOUNT',
    'campaignGroups': 'MY_CAMPAIGN_GROUP',
    'count':100,
}

# Get analytics data by paginating
url_stack = [base_url]
while url_stack:

    # Pop the url in the list, now the list is empty
    wurl = url_stack.pop()

    # Make request to API
    r = requests.get(wurl, params=params, headers=headers)

    if r.ok:
        print('Request success')
        print('URL of successful request:\n- {}\n'.format(r.url))
    else:
        print('Request fail')
        print('URL of failed request:\n- {}'.format(r.url))
        print('Request detail:\n- {}\n'.format(r.json()))

    # If paging information exists in the response,
    if 'paging' in r.json().keys():

        # Use the inforamtion for the next page by updating 'params' dict
        params['start'] = r.json()['paging']['start'] + r.json()['paging']['count']
        params['count'] = r.json()['paging']['count']

        # Append updated URL with next paging info
        url_stack.append(wurl)
```

And here is the output from the code above:

```
# Output:
Request success
URL of successful request:
- https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2/?q=analytics&dateRange.start.month=4&dateRange.start.day=1&dateRange.start.year=2019&timeGranularity=DAILY&pivot=CREATIVE&accounts=MY_ACCOUNT&campaignGroups=MY_CAMPAIGN_GROUP&count=100

Request fail
URL of failed request:
- https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adAnalyticsV2/?q=analytics&dateRange.start.month=4&dateRange.start.day=1&dateRange.start.year=2019&timeGranularity=DAILY&pivot=CREATIVE&accounts=MY_ACCOUNT&campaignGroups=MY_CAMPAIGN_GROUP&count=100&start=100
Request detail:
- {'serviceErrorCode': 2, 'message': 'Setting a paging start value is not permitted', 'status': 400}
```

From my understanding, and as mentioned in the document - ***To paginate through results, begin with a start value of 0 and a count value of N. To get the next page, set start value to N, while the count value stays the same. Subsequent pages start at 2N, 3N, 4N, and so on.***, I have to set the start value when passing request for n-th page but somehow it did not work what I intended!

Does anyone have similar experience and can anyone share how to resolve this? 
Or, please feel free to point me out what I'm doing it wrong in the code.

Thanks!

Comment: Because I am not working with an account that already has data, I cannot test it myself, but I noticed in the documentation, within the `paging` field of the response, there is a nested `links` field. Could this field possible contain a "next" link that would be used for paging?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue for yourself?

Comment: @ChristianReall-Fluharty Hey Christian, LinkedIn told me that 'AdAnalyticsV2' does not support pagination so if you have large data to fetch, try to increase the number of 'count' first. If doing this is not enough, you could try to divide your desired date range into pieces and fetch them one by one. Hope this helps. :)